# ko.applyBindings doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have this code in MVC 4 and the ko.applyBindings doesn't work. It's not making the binding. How can I make it work ?

This is my code in html:

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-append-double full-width">
            <input id="ProductName" placeholder="Product Name" data-binding="value: 

$root.vmProduct().ProductName" type="text"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This is my code in javascript/jquery:

```
 var ProductModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.ProductName = ko.observable();

            self.ProductName.subscribe(function (value) {
                console.log(value);
            }.bind(self));
        };

            viewModel.vmProduct.ProductName("Estera");
        };

        var viewModel = {
            vmProduct: new ProductModel()
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: I tried also data-binding="value:
viewModel.ProductName" and this doesn't work either.

Comment: try "value: vmProduct.ProductName"

Comment: You have a problem with the brackets. viewModel.vmProduct.ProductName("Estera");
        }; => It does not close anything

Comment: var ProductModel = function() {
            var self = this;
            self.ProductName = ko.observable();


            self.ProductName.subscribe(function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            }.bind(self));

        };

        var viewModel = {
            vmProduct: new ProductModel()
        };

        function PopulateKnockout() {

            viewModel.vmProduct.ProductName("Estera");
        }

       

        $(document).ready(function() {

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            PopulateKnockout();

        });

Comment: var ProductModel = function() {
            var self = this;
            self.ProductName = ko.observable();


            self.ProductName.subscribe(function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            }.bind(self));

        };

        var viewModel = {
            vmProduct: new ProductModel()
        };

        function PopulateKnockout() {

            viewModel.vmProduct.ProductName("Estera");
        }

       

        $(document).ready(function() {

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            PopulateKnockout();

        });

Comment: this is my code, it closes.

Comment: His code might have been not nicely pasted, but check my answer, also with better formatted code

Comment: @esterag this actually had me stumped for a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your data binding, instead of `data-binding` you should have had `data-bind`

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5B2hb/1/)

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-append-double full-width">
        <input id="ProductName" placeholder="Product Name" data-bind="value: vmProduct.ProductName" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is  the JS

```
var ProductModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.ProductName = ko.observable();

    self.ProductName.subscribe(function (value) {
        console.log(value);
    });
};
var viewModel = {
    vmProduct: new ProductModel()
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    viewModel.vmProduct.ProductName("Estera");
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using ko since yesterday, I don't know how I haven't noticed that earlier. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @esterag I missed it also, had it in fiddle and couldn't figure out why it was not working, then noticed the HTML

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `vmProduct` is not an observable itself, so when you do your `value` binding, you can do `value: vmPRoduct.ProductName` rather than `value: vmProduct().ProductName`

Also, not sure if it is just a cut and paste error, but this code looks a little out of place:

```
viewModel.vmProduct.ProductName("Estera");
```

Make sure that you are setting the value, after the `viewModel` has been created.

Comment: I also tried to use it like this value: vmProduct.ProductName, I am trying to display o the input "Estera" and it doesn't bind. I did this too "Make sure that you are setting the value, after the viewModel has been created.".